# PDO Function setFetchMode

Tags: php, function, pdo

Hello i was trying to make function with PDO but getting error (new to PDO) here is my code

```
    function mail_id($mail){
    global $host, $dbname, $user, $pass;
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $STH = $DBH->query("select count(from) from messages where from = '$mail'");
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $row = $STH->fetch();
    return $row;
}
```

i want to count row FROM and here is the out put i was trying

```
$mail=mail_id($userid);
if (0<count($mail['to_viewed'])) {echo "green";} else {echo "gray";}
```

this is the error

```
Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object
```

please help thx

Comment: Perhaps your SQL statement has an error in it?  I don't know if you can have a column named "from" (i.e. `count(from)`).  You might need to wrap it in tick marks or something.

Comment: i have a column with name FROM

Comment: FROM is a Keyword in SQL.  You need to wrap it in tick marks in your SQL statements when describing your column.

Comment: you can also do `var_dump($STH->errorInfo());` to get any sql errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the return value of [`PDO::query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php). In (ugly) PHP there are lots of functions that return a value of mixed type. In the case of `PDO::query()` the return type is either [`PDOStatement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) or bool, although the prototype in the documentation says something different:

> **Description:**
>   `PDOStatement PDO::query ( string $statement )`
>   `...`

Looks like it always returns `PDOStatement`.

> **Return Values:**
>   PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.

Oops, not in every case! Therefore you are not guaranteed that the value returned is a `PDOStatement`.

The correct prototype would be:

> **Description:**
>   `mixed PDO::query ( string $statement )`
>   `...`

In your case the query is invalid (by using a reserved keyword like FROM as a column name) which results in a return value of type boolean with the value FALSE. A boolean value is not an object and therefore your call to `$STH->setFetchMode()` fails.

Depending on your PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE you get

- an exception (PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION), so you don't need to check the
  return value
- a warning (PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING)
- nothing (PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT), so you have to check the return value, `errorCode()` and `errorInfo()`